# React Native android compilation: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, react-native

Everytime I build for android the default React Native projects, I get the following error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzc;
```

[image: error]

I followed all the instructions on the react native "get started" page.